# Allow iOS user to email a PDF from the app bundle

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, email, app-bundle

Is it possible to allow the iOS user to email a locally stored PDF document (contained within the app bundle)?

I already have a function in my project that allows the user to email the link of the page the webView is displaying, but I would like them to be able to email the locally stored PDF rather than just a link to a corresponding web address.

When I touch "Mail link to this Page" it creates a link to the local document like `file:///...`

I'm using this to display the local file:

```
SVModalWebViewController *webViewController = [[SVModalWebViewController alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Military-Storage-Solutions" ofType:@"pdf"]]];
```

Comment: xcode is just an IDE and irrelevant for this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be easy for you to access the file directly and obtain it's data, and after that, using MFMailComposeViewController insert the following code somewhere:

```
NSData *data = // pdf data
NSString *fileName = @"thename.pdf";
NSString *mimeType = @"proper pdf mimetype";

[mailComposeViewController addAttachmentData:data mimeType:mimeType fileName:fileName];
```